# jquery tooltip strange behavior

Tags: jquery, tooltip

```
function ShowToolTip() {
 var values = document.getElementById('HiddenEmbedptt').value;
 if (values == "True") {
    alert(1);
   $("#flashbanner").tooltip({
        bodyHandler: function() {
            return $("#divDesc").html();
        },
        track: true,
        showURL: false,
        delay: 0
    });
 }
}
```

The above code is used to display the tooltip. But the strange behavior is when I add the alert, the tooltip content is visible and when I dont add the alert, the tooltip content is not visible.

**HTML code with alert**

```
<div id="tooltip" style="display: block; top: 100px; left: 46px; right: 0pt;"   
class="viewport-right"><h3 style="display: none;"></h3><div class="body">My Tooltip  
Text</div><div class="url" style="display: none;"></div></div>
```

**HTML code without alert**

```
<div id="tooltip" style="display: block; left: 46px; right: 0pt; top: 100px;"><h3></h3>
<div class="body"></div><div class="url"></div></div>
```

I am not sure what could be the reason and how an alert could change the code behavior?

**Edit:**

```
function getPlayerWidth() {
alert(1);
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
    $("#first").text("e.pageX: " + e.pageX + ", e.pageY: " + e.pageY);
    if (e.pageX >= 73 && e.pageX <= 340  ) {
        //$("#divDesc").css({float:"right",position:"absolute",right:"0",clear:"left"});
        $("#tooltip").css({display:"block",left:"46px",right:"0",top:"100px",color:"red !important"});
    }
    if (e.pageY >= 4 && e.pageX <= 290) {
        //$("#divDesc").css({float:"right",position:"absolute",right:"0",clear:"left"});
        $("#tooltip").css({ display: "block", left: "46px", right: "0", top: "100px", color: "red !important" });
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What the alert could change is the *order* of events in your code, as an alert is blocking further javascript execution, this could mean that other critical actions could have time to occur before your code is executed.

For instance, if `ShowToolTip` is called before `DOMReady`, there might not be a `#flashbanner` element, but if you introduce an alert, the DOM will have time to load, and the element will be found by the time the javascript engine continues to execute that particular piece of code.

Is a `DOMReady` listener what you're missing?

```
$(function() {
    ShowToolTip();
});
```

Comment: Yeah ShowToolTip() is called as given by you but still the behavior is same

Comment: There is never any C# code involved in problems like this. At best, C# is being used to generate the problematic code. The problem is not with the code you've pasted [as you can tell by this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W6hYz/). The problem is with the order of events, that the pause that an alert introduces, is somehow altering. `DOMReady` would be an example of such an outcome-changing event. An AJAX call would be another. If my answer doesn't help you work out what's missing, then we'll need to see more code to be able to assist, because the problem is not with the code pasted.

Comment: Added another piece of code that is called before ShowToolTip()